# USB Type-C 10Gb mux, or hub IC

Tags: usb-c, usb-host, usb-hub

I am planning to create a PCB that takes the Type-C frontpanel header, with a speed of 10 Gbps and provides two USB Type-C ports from that one cable.

The PCB will be a frontpanel mod.

During my IC research I looked at the [Texas Instruments Mux/Redrivers products](https://www.ti.com/interface/usb/redrivers-multiplexers/products.html), but I can't seem to find what I need, or I can't seem to understand the purpose of some of the products being offered.

Prefferably I'd like the system to work as following.
When a single USB C plug is connected, the 10 Gbps data path is not altered, but when a second USB C plug is inserted, the total bandwidth get's split up in half. By the way, the IC connects to the USB Type-C port of my (Windows) motherboard, so the IC should work out of the box.

So,

10 Gbps USB Type-C input (1x) -> 10 Gbps USB Type-C output (1x)

or

10 Gbps USB Type-C input (1x) -> 5 Gbps USB Type-C output (2x)

Is this even possible?

Comment: Unless you are familiar with high speed PCB design and have a good grasp on what you are trying to do entails, my advice would be to buy a commercial USB-C hub, it'll be cheaper and easier.

Comment: @TomCarpenter That is true! But I'm designing a frontpanel mod so that won't be a solution I'm affraid

Comment: You're not being realistic about this.  We can't stop you from wasting time and money building something that won't work, but you were warned that without orders of magnitude more board design experience, it's not going to.

Answer (score 1):

> but when a second USB C plug is inserted, the total bandwidth get's split up in half. By the way, the IC connects to the USB Type-C port of my (Windows) motherboard, so the IC should work out of the box.

"Split up by half" doesn't make sense in the context of USB. It's a bus. If your devices can even provide more than half of 10 Gb/s, then it's up to your operating system to provide bus time to both devices, according to demand. Typically, operating systems are smart about that, and also, USB has special modes so that devices that need a fixed rate (say, a video camera) get a guaranteed time slot regularly.

So, what you describe is actually a USB hub. Pretty standard. An USB hub can be USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gb/s) upstream, and any combination of equal or lower wire speeds downstream. Since only one device is asked to transmit data at a time from the host, the "sharing" happens controlled by the host; it's not your responsibility (or even opportunity) to implement that.

Neither a redriver nor a mux can do what you want. You need a hub IC.

Buy a USB hub. Building a USB3.1 Superspeed+ device requires high-speed layout and circuit design experience, which you quite frankly don't have; this is more than just putting a few traces from A to B. A commercially available hub is 20 to 30€ plus taxes. No way you're even getting close to that price on a design that will need chips that you buy in single-digit quantities and for which you need at least a 4-layer PCB (not to mention that few things work on the first try...).

Comment: It's kind of a rough answer with a lot of assumptions, like I've mentioned in my edited question, this PCB is used as a frontpanel mod, so buying an hub is not really an option. Furthermore, I don't really learn if I do not make mistakes ;-). The hub IC's that are out there are all USB 3.0 and USB 2.0, I haven't found one that could also handle USB 3.1 Gen 2

Comment: Couple of companies make them, I think pretty much the only one you'll be able to buy (since you're not buying > 10000 of them) will be the Microchip Inc. one. Again, this is not a project on which you **can** learn a lot. You need expensive (like, building-level expensive) measurement equipment to see what's wrong if it doesn't work on the first try - and it won't work on the first try. If you want to learn something about high-speed digital buses, start with something easier. PCIe 1.0 is, in fact, easier, for example. If you want something that works:doing it yourself is really not an option

Comment: But, I give you that it's a good approach to look at what other people write about their designs to learn about the design approach. I guess microchip has reference designs for their USB 3.1 gen 2 hub ICs; buy one of these (any other designer would do the same and base her/his design on what Microchip did),and learn from that and the guides,application notes and layout files that came with it.I promise you'll learn more if you first learn a bit about high-speed design in general,i.e. from a book,instead of being confronted with a "magical" design where you can't know what's important (or not).

Comment: (The reason why you don't find a lot of USB 3.1 Gen 2 hub ICs, by the way, is that there's not that many IC companies that can invest into a product design that requires such high speeds, and because there's a limited amount of different designs a customer of these companies would want to try, as prototyping boards with such high bandwidth can get a bit expensive)

Comment: thanks! This is something I can do something with. I found the USB7252 USB Hub IC which looks like it is able do it all. I'll look into designing high speed PCB's first and try to learn something from it.